# SELECT "NOT IN", INNER JOIN and COUNT in SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to select which co-ordinates from OA table are NOT found in the CUSTOMER address table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       OA.CO_ORDS
FROM    
        CUSTOMER
INNER JOIN  
        OA ON customer.address=oa.co_ords
ORDER BY ID ASC;
```

Returns the co-ordinates which ARE in the customer table. How do I return those that are not in the customer table?

Am I also able to COUNT how many of customers are is in each co-ordinate (The co-ords are not specific and not accurate, this is purely for query testing only)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
           OA.CO_ORDS
    FROM    
            CUSTOMER
    INNER JOIN  
            OA ON customer.address=oa.co_ords
    ORDER BY ID ASC;
```

Comment: Your inner join requires the records to be in both tables.  Use an outer join (left/right) to get all records from one table such as `SELECT OA.CO_ORDS FROM OA LEFT JOIN Customer on Customer.address=oa.co_ords WHERE customer.address is null`  though not exists is problaby the best since it doesn't have to execute the join.  no in can be problematic if nulls can be introduced.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `NOT EXISTS` to find those co-ordinates which don't appear in the customer table:

```
SELECT co_ords
FROM oa
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 FROM customers 
      WHERE address = oa.co_ords)
ORDER BY id;
```

In order to count how many customers belong to a certain co-ordinate, we can use `COUNT` with `GROUP BY`, something like this:

```
SELECT c.address, COUNT(*)
FROM customers c
JOIN oa 
  ON c.address = oa.co_ords
GROUP BY c.address;
```

It could be better to count a specific column instead of *.

It could also be better to use an `IN` clause instead of `JOIN` the tables:

```
SELECT c.address, COUNT(*)
FROM customers c
WHERE address IN 
  (SELECT co_ords FROM oa)
GROUP BY c.address;
```

Such details depend on your exact table structure, you should please try this out or provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
SELECT co_ords
FROM   oa
MINUS
SELECT address
FROM   customers;
```

which can sometimes be faster than doing an anti-join. Note that `MINUS` does a distinct on the resultset.